# How can I install a bitcoin wallet on Kali Linux?

Tags: wallet, coldstorage, offline, storage, safety

I got Kali Linux installed on my laptop and I want to install a good bitcoin wallet to store my bitcoins offline.As I know,top 5 best bitcoin wallets would be Bitcoin Core (the first offline wallet),Multibit (lightweight),Electrum,Blockchain Wallet and Hive.I would like to know how to install one or more of these,or at least another wallet,but if it's one that I haven't listed,I'd also want some basic information about it and obviously the installation guide.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the official guide to building Bitcoin on Linux:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md